# Cross-domain SVG content document in object tag

Tags: javascript, html, svg, cross-domain

Is it 'legal' to have an SVG with a data in a foreign domain i.e. (data="//da86ge957603k.cloudfront.net/rails/grafitti_logo-f4e8238a87c979c0cf5b41481c982b71.svg"), and then bind a load event to the object and then access the object's SVG DOM through the contentdocument property?  I can do this when the SVG is on the local domain, but whenever I try to host the SVG elsewhere, I get "this.contentDocument is null" errors.  I have tried getSVGDocument() as well.  I can't find anywhere that says this is a cross-domain security problem, and from what I can tell this should be permissible with an object tag being used for the SVG (I am not using an iFrame).  I appreciate you taking the time to help me.  Here is the code I am using to embed the object and bind, and try to access the DOM (as I said this works when the SVG is on the local domain).

```
 <object id="gangstergraffiti" type="image/svg+xml" data="<%= image_url("grafitti_logo.svg") %>">Gangster</object>

$("#gangstergraffiti").each(function() {
  this.addEventListener('load', svgGangsterGraffitiReady, false);
});

function svgGangsterGraffitiReady(){
  var graffitistrokes = this.contentDocument.getElementsByClassName('graffiti');
  for (var i = 0; i < graffitistrokes.length; i++) {
    graffitistrokes[i].setAttribute("stroke", "white");
    graffitistrokes[i].setAttribute("fill", "white");
  }
}
```

Comment: UAs should prevent this. If you control the remote site you may be able to set up CORS to get around this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  It looks like it is being prevented, I just can't find the fact that this is the expected behavior documented anywhere.  I'll give you the point for answering.

Comment: Hi @dps, did you manage to make this work? I'm unable to force any browser to do a preflight request before loading the resource, and that seems to be the reason why I can't access the content document. The implementation I have seems to be identical to yours.

Comment: @Kukosk it's been a while but I think I eventually used a SVGInjector which will load an SVG from a remote URL and inject it directly into the DOM, take a look at this: https://github.com/iconic/SVGInjector

Comment: @dps Yes, my guess also was that this method would work, but I'm trying to avoid it if possible. Sadly, from what I've read it seems I won't be able to :( I guess I will have to stick with my current proxy implementation. Thank you for the response :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's documented [here by w3c](http://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy). In [detail here for the object tag](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/embedded-content.html#the-object-element) that you can't do cross domain access to the data of a `<object>` tag except via CORS.

There's a [more readable distillation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) and to get round it you need to [enable CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) on the remote site (if you can).