# How to view secure intranet sites by handling Access-Control_Allow_Origin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have written a simple html file to display the page provided by a hyper link under the table in the same page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
  $('.link').on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $("#content").html('<object data='+href+' />');
    return false;
  });       
});
</script>
<style>
object {
  width: 1570px;
  height: 1000px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
</style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#EBF5FB">
<h1 align="center" >SLA Monitor Reports </h1>
<div align="center">

<table cellpadding="25px" border=1>    
<tr>

<td><a class="link" href="https://www.wikipedia.org/"><img src="\\TSHomeServer\TSHome$\231456\Downloads\1ITD.png" alt="SRs Proposed Due Date" style="width:200px"></a></td>
<td><a class="link" href="https://bwp.wdf.nova.corp/irj/servlet/prt/portal/prtroot/pcd!3aportal_content!2fcom.nova.pct!2fplatform_add_ons!2fcom.sap.ip.bi!2fiViews!2fcom.nova.ip.bi.bex?BOOKMARK=CU4A95OJ17A355B2112ML30G6"><img src="\\TSHomeServer\TSHome$\231456\Downloads\1Google.png" alt="Ticket Aging" style="width:200px"></a></td>
</tr>
</table>
<br><br>
</div>
<div id="content">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The first hyper link which is targeted to wikipedia.org is properly displayed in a div under the table.

But when i try to access the second link which is an intranet site pointed to a bw report hosted in a intranet server,i get a access-control-allow-origin error and the page keeps on trying to validate against the bw server.

But if i try to open the same intranet link in a new browser window..it validates and i can access the BW report.

Can you please let me know how to access the same BW report in the same page using div tag and handle this Access-Control_Allow_Origin issue.

Comment: the server needs to respond with such CORS headers - however, the "code" you've shown shouldn't have any CORS issues as it's a static page - the problem seems to be in `https://bwp.wdf.nova.corp/irj/servlet/prt/portal/prtroot/pcd!3aportal_content!2fcom.nova.pct!2fplatform_add_ons!2fcom.sap.ip.bi!2fiViews!2fcom.nova.ip.bi.bex?BOOKMARK=CU4A95OJ17A355B2112ML30G6` - but I take it you've opened that link in a new tab, and don't get any CORS errors ... how very odd

Comment: This is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26303655/cross-domain-svg-content-document-in-object-tag  In order to view the intranet site inside `object` element, the intranet server need to enable CORS.