# SVG contentDocument null for Content-Encoding: gzip

Tags: javascript, dom, svg, gzip, deflate

I have an SVG inside an object tag. I notice that if I store the SVG uncompressed, and serve it with "Transfer-Encoding: gzip", the image renders properly and I am able to access its contentDocument.

If I store the SVG compressed (as svg.gz) and use "Content-Encoding: gzip", the image renders properly on the page, however I get a "contentDocument is null" error when I try to access it (even after it has fully loaded).

Why does this happen, and is there any way I can access the contentDocument of pre-compressed SVG objects? I am using Firefox 60 on Ubuntu.

Comment: Are you waiting for the load event. If not this is probably a timing issue.

Comment: The contentDocument request is user-triggered, and returns null for gzip even after waiting several minutes.

Comment: Is the gzip document served from the same domain as the host document?

Comment: Good point. I realize after your question that the cross-domain is responsible, not gzip. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26303655/cross-domain-svg-content-document-in-object-tag gave me further insights. Thank you!